# How would you input sequential data?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, input

Let's say I want a user to enter a sequence, such as boxing combos (e.g., jab-cross-hook) or even skateboarding tricks, along with individual moves/tricks, how would you go about designing the UX for this? I initially thought about doing something like [Input of sequential data](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/94866/input-of-sequential-data), where items are tags set with a comma, and sequences are created by tags separated by spacebar and distinguished by a shared background (similar to date ranges inside of date pickers), but was curious to see any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Is this for data input (in which case you want it to be as painless as possible) or for a game (in which case you sometimes want to make special combo's difficult and the reward is in mastering them)?

Q2. How many different individual elements are there? 12 or less? If so you could map them to the function keys on a standard keyboard and let people rattle them out with the space bar to separate combos - plus, like 80/90s flight simulators, you could give them a printable keyboard overlay to indicate which key is which (just be a single strip for 12 keys). On a mobile you could give them an input pad. Just as an idea for something less repetitive and verbose (in KLM terms - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke-level_model) than typing commas and numbers.

Comment: It's for data input. User would fill in something like an async autocomplete textarea, select from hundreds of options, and select one or multiple (assuming selections turn into tags). She would then be able to create a sequence out of two or more selections. I'm struggling with how the user would create sequences, or how to visually represent a sequence.

Comment: Hundreds of options? Then I think your first issue will be how users choose from those options (type-ahead, categories/sub-categories?) rather than how to combine/separate and represent those selections. That can come afterwards.